# Safe way to reset login account

Tags: android, privacy, login-control

I am developing an app that will allow users to store and encrypt information, some of it may be sensitive. Recently the question came up "what if the user loses the password?" Currently there is no way to recover a lost password in this app. I would like to avoid having the app send any information to my servers for privacy concerns. I thought of maybe setting up a way that would reset the login information by putting a specific phrase into the username and password fields, which the user would request by email. However I am not sure if this is a good idea. Are there better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: why don't you send a temp password to the user email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most secure way for you to handle password resets is most likely using reset tokens. Whenever a user requests to reset a password, you create a new token which is valid for perhaps 15 mins or until used. You then send a link to the user's email with a url that looks something like `website.tld/reset?user=username&token=aRandomToken`. On the reset page, the user can choose a new password. That way, you won't have to deal with creating random passwords which you send in plain text to a user. An even more secure way would be to hash the user, so the `user` parameter would be a hash, and the user then has to enter their username on the reset page. That way, a hacker with the link can't just look at the url, but will actually need to know the username.

For sake of ease, an implementation could look something like:

```
var reset = new PasswordReset;
reset.user = realUsername;
reset.token = md5(randString(5) + date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
reset.save();

var url = 'website.tld/reset?user=' + md5(realUsername) + '&token=' + reset.token;

// send an email to the user with the url
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Phroggyy. It sounds like I have quite a bit of work ahead of me. Just so I know if I got the logic of this worked out right. On the device I would hash the username: then if a user forgets the password the hashed username would then be sent over to the webpage for checking. The webpage asks for the username, hashes it, then checks to see if hashes match? if match the user gets a reset token that will unlock the app. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I don't see why you would hash the username client-side. Basically, user enters the username when they request a password reset, you then generate a url of the form I described earlier, with the `user` parameter being the hashed username. Then you let the user enter the username again when recovering, and you check that the hash in the url matches the hashed username

Comment: I was thinking that in order for the program and the website to have the same hash it would have to be made on the client first. Apparently this is not the case. I will go ahead and mark this as answered but it seems I have some research to do on how it works.